# create email via opensrs api in ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openssl, email

I am developing a ruby on rails project to create email using Opensrs Api in ruby. For now, I can run opensrs commands in console log in via openssl to create email under each domain_name.

But now I am stuck with integrating that code to my Rails Project. It seem like I can log the the opensrs server, but cannot run their commands to create email.

Anyone know how to use openssl to run opensrs command via ruby code?

Code I am using:

```
require 'socket'
require 'openssl'
p "1---------------"

tcp_client = TCPSocket.new 'admin.test.hostedemail.com', 4449

context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_client, context

ssl_client.connect

ssl_client.write_nonblock "hello ========"
ssl_client.print "print hello ========"
ssl_client.write "write hello ========"

ssl_client.write_nonblock "ver ver='3.6'"
p ssl_client.readlines
p "2---------------"
```

Result:

"1---------------"

"2---------------"

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and ended up writing a gem for it:

https://github.com/strikingly/opensrs-email

We have been using this in production for a while and it solves our problem.

Feel free to take a look, fork, or send pull requests.